# Function which return html from an input string

Tags: php

Define a function that covert a string to a valid html with these rules:

- `_C` must be replaced with `<br/>`
- `**Hello World**` must be replaced with `<i>Hello World<i/>`
- `__Hello World__` must be replaced with `<strong>Hello World<strong/>`

MY TRY...

```
$str = "Hi my name is __Matteo__and, _C I'm **Italian**";

function replaceString($str){

    $newStr = str_replace("__", " <strong> ", $str);
    $newStr = str_replace("**", "<i>", $newStr);
    $newStr = str_replace("_C", "<br/>", $newStr);

    return "<p>" . $newStr . "<p/>";
}
```

I don't know how to close the tag `<i>` and `<strong>`

Any help?

Comment: Is this homework? If you looked around you can find a parser.

Comment: Can you format the requirements properly? Maybe you want to have a look at regular expressions?

Comment: How many underscores before `C`?

Comment: [Here](http://parsedown.org/) and [this](https://github.com/erusev/parsedown/issues/262). (Stop deleting my comment, there is nothing wrong with it)

Comment: @Script47 Editor has altered the OP.

Comment: @mickmackusa only one   =>  _C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this were my task, I'd use a non-regex str_replace for the `_C`.  Then use regex for the portions with opening/closing tags.

Code: (Demo: https://3v4l.org/26oGk )

```
$str = "Hi my name is __Matteo__and, _C I'm **Italian**";

function replaceString($str){
    $str = str_replace("_C", "<br/>", $str);
    $str = preg_replace(['~__([^_]+)__~', '~\*\*([^*]+)\*\*~'], ['<strong>$1</strong>', '<i>$1</i>'], $str);
    return "<p>" . $str . "<p/>";
}

echo replaceString($str);
```

Output:

```
<p>Hi my name is <strong>Matteo</strong>and, <br/> I'm <i>Italian</i><p/>
```

My regex patterns use negated character classes `[^...]` because they allow the regex engine to move with higher efficiency. Capture groups allow you to isolate the wrapped substrings and apply new wrappings in the replacement.

Comment: didn't know you could use arrays with preg_replace, neat.

Comment: you sure `__.*?__` wouldn't be faster?

Comment: See for yourself at regex101.  When you ask the regex engine to match greedily it can "move faster". When you make the quantifier lazy, you lose efficiency.

Comment: damn, you're right, your rex is definitely much faster